# Getting a working virtual Zoom background on 18.04

Tags: video, zoom-meeting

When I use a zoom virtual background, my face looks like it belongs to a monster, and things like the couch in the room show through. In short it's hopeless.    Is there some way to get a decent virtual background in ubuntu/zoom?    I've read about `deepbacksub`  but haven't seen how to download it.

And the article [Background Substitution, No Green Screen Required](https://hackaday.com/2020/04/10/background-substitution-no-green-screen-required/) seems to have figured out how to do it, but replicating the author's code is way beyond my ability.      Is there software that I can simply `apt` to get a decent background?

I'm running the most recent version of zoom, dated 09/2020.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial to get virtual background to work on Linux: [Ubuntu Zoom Virtual Background without physical green screen](https://leftsidemonitor.com/ubuntu-zoom-virtual-background-without-physical-green-screen/)